# Creation of a Custom Data Entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, custom-activity

I would like to know if it's possible to create a custom data entry that pulls in data via an external database hosted in heroku. Will it be opening an API on my side? or would i be posting on a scheduled basis to a specific API in SFMC?

As of now, majority of the answers has been to pull in data via existing data extensions. And if so, am i able to replicate the functionality of how Salesforce Data Entries work?

My current connection is SFDC <-> Marketing Cloud Connect <-> SFMC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make calls to the Journey Builder API from your side in a similar way to the fashion CRM Flows make calls to the Journey Builder [Events API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) for Salesforce Data entry events. The actual Salesforce events make use of an undocumented batch endpoint interaction-experimental/v1/batchcontactevents which is very similar, but allows you to fire multiple events in a single call.

If you have some means of configuring triggers in your Heroku DB somewhat like the Flows defined by the Salesforce Data UI in Journey Builder, it's possible extend Journey Builder, see a [Sample Entry Event and UI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-contact-decision-event.htm). Not trivial and you may find it easier to just to fire regular API Events from Heroku.

Comment: Hi Macca. Am i able to just check with you that if i were to use that Events API directly from Heroku, i'll be pushing in a data payload that would immediately enter the journey with the specific data?

Is there a DE that must be created beforehand or is this via the API entry?

Comment: You need to define a Data Extension first. That could be done by a Custom Event app, potentially, much as the standard CRM events do. But if you're happy just rolling your own DE in Marketing Cloud with the attributes you need and then pointing a new API Event at your DE (created in the Entry Sources tab of JB) then you can fire your API calls at this Event Definition, the data gets written to your DE and Contacts are fired into the Journey you decide to hook up to that Event Definition.

Comment: Awesome! i'll test it out and get back to u on it. Cheers!